# How can I specify custom jar name in Gradle for PlayFramework application

Tags: gradle, plugins, playframework, jar, configuration

With regards to the play framework plugin for gradle:

In the generated executable playBinary file that is created in build/stage/playBinary/bin/, there is a line that reads:

```
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/src.jar
```

The last part, "src.jar" seems to be determined by the root directory that your assets were compiled in. For example if you ran gradle dist from a directory named "AProject", the classpath would instead be:

```
CLASSPATH=$APP_HOME/lib/AProject.jar
```

Is it possible to override this name in the :createPlayBinaryJar task so that I can set this to be deterministic and agnostic of where assets are compiled?